# Go to path & read txt file with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a list full of directories and I want to loop through those directories and open the txt file. Then read the data inside that txt file and assign to a variable.

This is an example of the directory list looks like:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[ Go! Go! Heaven!!]_____________25 -______ ___- [525067]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[12CUT] _____ (Gakkou no Kaidan) [518382]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[2____] _____!__CD__________ [521206]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[Ability] _____________________ [514182]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[Abo Manten] Kyuusho seme maniacs vol. 3 (Weak Spot Maniacs vol.3) [521993]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[Afro] Futanari angel cg collection [521560]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[Aim-ZERO] Case Vol.4 [519927]\test.txt
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\[Air Hike] ________CG_2 [525114]\test.txt
```

Now here's the code

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, strTextFile, strData, strLine, arrLines
CONST ForReading = 1

'name of the text file
strTextFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\ArtistCG\folders.txt"

'Create a File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Open the text file - strData now contains the whole file
strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTextFile,ForReading).ReadAll

'Split the text file into lines
arrLines = Split(strData,vbCrLf)

'Step through the lines
For Each strLine in arrLines
wscript.echo strLine
Next

'Cleanup
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Now the problem with the code is it reads the data of folders.txt instead of going to the directory and read the test.txt file. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
wscript.echo strLine
```

you need to do this:

```
text = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strLine, ForReading).ReadAll
```

This would, however, overwrite the content of the variable `text` with each iteration, so you need to decide if you want to go the text of all files into a single variable (append the text read from the file to the variable) or into separate variables (read each file into a separate field of an array or something like that).

Comment: I'm already doing that, ain't I? However, if by "help me write the code" you actually mean "write the code for me", the answer would be no. I can explain what you need to do, but I do expect you to put it together yourself. So, do you need the content all files in one variable, or each content in a separate variable?